# Is it possible to give a button associated information?

Tags: c#, wpf

Sorry if the question doesn't make much sense in C# terms. I've been programming in Obj-C and over there, you could give a button a "tag".

I'm asking because I'm programmatically creating a lot of buttons and having them share the same method for MouseDoubleClick. The problem is, I don't have a way to discern which button pressed it without a "tag". Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: what i do is name them btnxx where the xx parts is a number is that what you want?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "Tag" property exists on a button and it accepts an `object` which means you can assign whatever you want to it

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.110).aspx - button inherits from `FrameworkElement` (I believe it's `Button->Control->UIComponent->FrameworkElement` - edit: no it's FrameworkElement->UIElement ... close but no cigar :))

Comment: Aside from the fact that the tag takes an object, so you can give it whatever you want, you should know which button caused the event because all the events have a `sender` argument which is *the sender*. If you really need to attach more information to a button, you can use `Tag`, but you might eventually be better off sub-classing.

Comment: @Charleh That is true but entirely misses the point of his question.  The WPF `Tag` and the Cocoa `Tag` are not in any way related.

Comment: Well, you *can* use tag for this purpose but it's not a good idea when you can use a ref to the actual button, I probably should have been a bit more responsible in my comment (I usually am)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `Tag` Property on every `FrameworkElement` so you could solve it this way.

If you want to use a more WPFier way, you should consider using a ViewModel with an `ICommand` Implementation. This Command can receive a parameter where you can pass e.g. an integer (or an enum value, which could be more maintainable). This should be bound to the `Command` Property instead of a common EventHandler.

Comment: This kind-of misses the point.  Why not just use the name of the button?  The `Tag` property is appropriate for this in Cocoa, not so much in WPF.

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid now for not even checking. Wasn't expecting for this to even exit in C# haha Thanks :)

On a sidenote, @mydogisbox, I need a numerical tag because I'm using it to access a List :)

Comment: @Dilisqq ah, so you don't need to know which button was pressed, you just need some associated information.  Maybe you could update your question to clarify that?  Otherwise this answer will mislead people into thinking the `Tag` property is the correct way to identify UI controls!

Comment: Ah, will do!! :) Sorry, it made complete sense to me from an Obj-C standpoint

Comment: @mydogisbox No the `Tag` property ist not in any way ment to identify an object, you're completely right with that. I plain answered the question if there's a `Tag` property and tried to show another way which is imho more appropriate. For identifying a control your solution is of course the correct way.

Answer (score 3):

If you define a button in xaml like this:

```
<Button x:Name="nameOfButtonToIdentify"/>
```

the `x:Name` tag defines the name of the control.

If you then had an event handler for it like this:

```
private void nameOfButtonToIdentify_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

you could check to see if the `nameOfButtonToIdentify` button had been clicked like this:

```
private void nameOfButtonToIdentify_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(sender == nameOfButtonToIdentify)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

The `Button` type has a `Tag` property, but it is merely a property for storing arbitrary information rather than a means of identifying that control.

Comment: I think you want `((Button)sender).Name == btnName` as you are comparing apples/oranges at the moment :) (unless of course btnName is a ref to the button...!)

Comment: they would only want that if btnName wasn't a button but i believe that is in this example

Comment: Been a while since I've touched WPF yes you are right the generated code behind has a matching member that references the button!

Comment: @Charleh if you look at the Xaml I posted, `btnName` is the name of the button.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I think the variable name threw me off

Answer (score 0):

like my comment said this is what i do

```
int numberForButton =0;
for (int i =0;i<100;i++)
{
    Button but = new Button();
    //usual place button fields
    but.MouseDoubleClick += click_event;
    but.Name = btn+numberForButton;
    numberForButton++;
}


private void btnName_Click(object sender, MouseDoubleClick_event e)
{
    //for button 97 chosen at random
    if(((Button)Sender).Name.SubString(2) == 97)
    {
        //code what you want button 97 to do
    }
}
```

This creates 100 buttons in the c# part of your work and all call the same event where the comment is put code to place buttons where you like change the 100 to however many buttons you want and off you go

Comment: You're missing the bit where you distinguish between which button was clicked.

Comment: I think you meant "97".  What you currently have won't compile.

Comment: Think i have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Lamdba to call the same method with different results.
It's faster if you need to pass specific parameters to your Clickmethod

```
foreach(var element in list)
{
    //...

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Click += (s,e) => YourClickMethod(element.Property);
}
```